# Probability of a defective part

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I was wondering if my solution to the question below is correct. I am unsure of my event set.

16 parts are examined for defects. It is found that 10 are good, 4 have minor
defects, and 2 have major defects. Two parts are chosen at random from the 16
without replacement, that is, the first part chosen is not returned to the mix
before the second part is chosen. Notice, then, that there will be only 15 possible choices for the second part.

a) What is the probability that both are good?

b) What is the probability that exactly one part has a major defect?

A) Let g represent good parts, md minor defects, and Md major defects

Let R be the event.
R = {(g , g), (g , md), (g , Md)}

Therefore, the probability that both are good is, P[(g, g)] = 1/3.

b) P[(g, Md)] = 1/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) P(Both are good) = P(1st choice is good) * P(2nd choice is good) = (10/16)*(9/15) = 3/8

b) P(only one major defect) = 1 - {P(Both are good) + P(1st one is good)*P(2nd one is minor) + P(1st one is minor)*P(2nd one is good) + P(1st one is major)*P(2nd one is major) + P(1st one is minor)*P(2nd one is minor)) = 7/30

Comment: The second calculation is correct, but it might be easier to calculate directly as P(1st one is major)*P(2nd one is not major)+P(1st one is not major)*P(2nd one is major) = 2/16*14/15+14/16*2/15 = 7/30.

Comment: @JeremyDover Thanks! Lucifer's answer b) seems to have different answer from similar to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

a) P(first is good) and P(second is good)=(Total Good/Total)*((Total Good - 1)/Total-1)
product rule gives: 10/16*9/15

b) This part is simpler using the complement rule, you should be able to finish it. 
 P (exactly one has a major defect) = P (NOT BOTH) = 1 - P(....)

Answer (score 1):

A) Pr (both good) = Pr.(1st good when picked from 16 AND 2nd good when picked from the remaining 15) = (10/16)*(9/15) = 3/8
Note, the number of good parts also reduces by 1 to 9 in second draw (because without replacement).

B) Pr (Only one part has major defect) = Pr (Either first draw has major defect OR second draw has major defect) = (2/16)*(6/15) + (6/16)*(2/15) = 1/10

Comment: we have different answers, i'm curious how you came up with the number 6 in part b